# Python Fabric 2.4 no environment variables

Tags: python, ssh, environment-variables, freebsd, fabric

I have problem with fabic (2.4). I have no access to environment variables in remote server (I'm using FreeBSD).

In my ~/.profile file i have variable:

```
export MY_KEY="123456789"
```

In my fabfile.py i have simple task:

```
from fabric import task

@task(hosts=['user@myhost.com'])
def deploy(context):
    context.run('echo 123')
    context.run('echo $MY_KEY')
```

When I run the fab deploy command, I see only 123 but after connecting via ssh my variable is visible.

Comment: Just a rough guess but did you try ```context.run('env echo $MY_KEY')```?

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html

Comment: @accdias exact same thing, only 123.

Comment: So it must be related with the FAQ I pointed on my second comment.

Comment: @accdias I think it's because of non-interactive mode but i don't know how to change it.

Comment: It certainly is and you need to experiment with the workarounds suggested there.

Answer (score 0):

And what about using `Connection.prefix` as a context manager ?

```
with context.prefix('MY_KEY="123456789"'):
    context.run('echo 123')
    context.run('echo $MY_KEY')
```

Comment: I get 'prefix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'My_KEY'

Comment: Please put 'MY_KEY="123456789"' between single quotes. It's a string, not the value of a keyword argument named MY_KEY